# json to html table based on key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

This is the json file i have, basically i want to create tables based on ids for this example, id : 50 should be showed in one table where as id : 57 should be shown in another table on the same

```
 {
    "version": "5.2",
    "user_type": "online",
    "user":
    [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "id": 50
        },
        {
            "name": "Mark",
            "id": 50
        },
       {
            "name": "Mark",
            "id": 57
       }
   ]
}
```

the code used to generate the table

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "http://PATH/user.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache:false,
    success: function(data){
        /*console.log(data);*/
        $('<tr><td colspan="3"><b>Heading ONE</b></td></tr>').insertBefore('table > thead > tr:first');
        var event_data = '';
        $.each(data.user, function(index, value){
            /*console.log(value);*/
            event_data += '<tr>';
            event_data += '<td>'+value.name+'</td>';
            event_data += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
            event_data += '</tr>';
        });
        $("#list_table_json").append(event_data);
    },
    error: function(d){
        /*console.log("error");*/
        alert("404. Please wait until the File is Loaded.");
    }
});
});
</script>
```

how do i get two tables ?
or should the json be changed

The output am getting is id 50 and 57 is the same table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zw9sy5ew/2/)**.

```
<div id="list_table_json">

</div>
```

I have used JSON directly in my code, in AJAX just make sure you parse the JSON first using `$.parseJSON`.

```
var data = $.parseJSON("{\"version\":\"5.2\",\"user_type\":\"online\",\"user\":[{\"name\":\"John\",\"id\":50},{\"name\":\"Mark\",\"id\":50},{\"name\":\"Johnny\",\"id\":57}]}");

var table;
$.each(data.user, function(key, value) {
  var row = $("<tr/>");

  if ($('table#main_table_' + value.id).length)
    table = $("#main_table_" + value.id);
  else
    table = $('<table></table>');
  table.attr('id', 'main_table_' + value.id);

  row.append($("<td/>").text(value.name));
  row.append($("<td/>").text(value.id));

  table.append(row);

  $("#list_table_json").append(table);
  $("#list_table_json").append("<br>");
});
```

Comment: thanks, worked well, how do i add an <th></th> for both table

Answer (score 0):

Try **jsonToTable()**:

```
<div id="list_50_table"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="list_57_table"></div>


function jsonToTable(data) {
  var table = $('<table></table>');
  $(data).each(function (i, rowData) {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>');
    $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
      row.append($('<td>'+cellData.name+'</td>'));
      row.append($('<td>'+cellData.id+'</td>'));
    });
    table.append(row);
  });
  return table;
}
$('#list_50_table').append(jsonToTable(data.user.filter(item => item.id === 50)))
$('#list_57_table').append(jsonToTable(data.user.filter(item => item.id === 57)))
```

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "http://PATH/user.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache:false,
    success: function(data){
       if(data && data !== " ") {
         $("#list_table_json").append(jsonToTable(data.user.filter(item => item.id === 50)));
         $("#list_table_json").append(jsonToTable(data.user.filter(item => item.id === 57)));
       } else {
          /*console.log("Sorry!");*/
          alert("Sorry no data found!");
       }
    },
    error: function(d){
        /*console.log("error");*/
        alert("404. Please wait until the File is Loaded.");
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: getting errors.. could post the full code.
(index):40 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at (index):40
(anonymous) @ (index):40
(index):16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at Object.success ((index):16)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Most likely $.ajax returned empty response instead of data. I have added a check for that. Let me know if it works.